# Azure Runbook - Get-AzStorageFileHandle

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-automation

I am trying to clear locks on file on a schedule using Azure Automation (Powershell / Runbook).
Can anyone point me in the right direction?

I have

```
$StorageContextfmgappservicelogs = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName 'fmgappservicelogs' -StorageAccountKey $StorageAccountKey 
Get-AzStorageFileHandle -ShareName "fmgappservicelogs" -Context $StorageContextfmgappservicelogs
Close-AzStorageFileHandle -ShareName "fmgappservicelogs" -Context $StorageContextfmgappservicelogs  -CloseAll
```

I get the following response

```
Get-AzStorageFileHandle : The term 'Get-AzStorageFileHandle' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, 
script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is 
correct and try again.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cmdlet `Get-AzStorageFileHandle` is not available in some older versions of az.storage module. So please make sure you're using the latest version `az.storage module 2.6.0`.

There are some ways to install the latest version of az.storage module 2.6.0.

For example, nav to azure portal -> your azure automation account -> Modules gallery -> in the search box, search "az.storage" -> click on it, and in the new page, check if the version is the latest one -> then click "Import" button. Here are the screenshots:

[image]

[image]

You can also use some other ways to import module as per this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/shared-resources/modules#import-modules).

Comment: amazing thank you! My brain didn't see the "Module Gallary". Would be great if Azure allowed modules to be updated and installed from within the "Modules" blade. Thanx for the help!